# Exception for grant create user

Tags: mysql-5.7, users

I'm trying to create an account (tenant) which has full privileges on all databases called test_...
It should also be able to create other users with also only privileges on those databases.

As root:

```
CREATE USER 'tenant'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '...';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test\_%`.* TO 'tenant'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'tenant'@'%';
```

As tenant:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_test;
CREATE USER 'tenant01'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '...';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test\_%`.* TO 'tenant01'@'%';
```

That's all cool, but I don't want tenant to be able to do this

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '...';
```

Can I set a special revoke for the root user? Can I do the grant create user differently?
Thank you for your help!